# How do I format my JSON?

Tags: json, format

I have JSON of this format

```
[
  {"name":"universityID","value":"454"},
  {"name":"grade","value":"88"},
  {"name":"date","value":"15-Jan-2016"},
  {"name":"address","value":"Washington"}
]
```

I want my JSON into

```
{
  "universityID":"454",
  "grade":"88",
  "date":"15-Jan-2016",
  "address":"Washington"
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @njzk2 lol. See the question again.

Comment: no but really... what language, what have you tried, what does not work, what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just iterate on your array and stuff each attribute into a new object as they come:

```js
var input = [
  {"name":"universityID","value":"454"},
  {"name":"grade","value":"88"},
  {"name":"date","value":"15-Jan-2016"},
  {"name":"address","value":"Washington"}
];

var output = {};

input.forEach(function(attr) {
  output[attr.name] = attr.value;
});

console.log(output);
```

EDIT: If `universityID` needs to be an array:

```js
var input = [
  {"name":"universityID","value":"454"},
  {"name":"grade","value":"88"},
  {"name":"date","value":"15-Jan-2016"},
  {"name":"address","value":"Washington"}
];

var output = {};

input.forEach(function(attr) {
  if (attr.name == "universityID") {
    if (!(attr.name in output)) output[attr.name] = [];
    output[attr.name].push(attr.value);
  } else {
    output[attr.name] = attr.value;
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: How do you do the same in jquery

Comment: The... same? This is vanilla JS and it doesn't need jQuery.

Comment: throws Uncaught TypeError: input.forEach is not a function. I am implementing in jquery.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did the same mistake I always complain about. Do you really have JSON (i.e. a string)? if so, you need to parse it first: `input = JSON.parse(inputString)`. If not... then either you're working with ancient browsers, or your input data is not as you have shown it.

Comment: Thanks @Amadam, It actually worked.  How do i manually add list like this in above result.                                                                                          {
  "universityID": ["454"],
  "grade": "88",
  "date": "15-Jan-2016",
  "address": "Washington"
}

Comment: Do you know in advance which fields will have an array? How do you figure out which fields do that?

Comment: In the back end i will pretty much expect array of universityIDs.                                    i.e. private List<Integer> universityID;